# Javaone 2011 video reports

Tags: java

Does anyone know where I can find video records from JavaOne 2011? I want to see some presentation, but can't find video archive.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Javaone 2011 channel on Parleys
http://www.parleys.com/#st=4&id=102979